# Looking for DEM data of Brighton UK

Tags: data, dem, united-kingdom

Where can I find accurate DEM data of Brighton UK with an attribute table to be used in ARC GIS, being used for a university GIS project and have struggled to find this data.

Comment: For open data I recommend researching/asking at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: For Brighton you can use the Point Cloud opendata from Environment Agency (England & Wales) that can be processed to even higher resolution data for DEMs. LIDAR-LAZ-2015-TQ20sw has more coverage than the more recent 2016 version.

Answer (score 7):

geostore 25cm, 50cm, 1m, 2m LiDAR
You will probably need to download a few tile to cover Brighton
http://www.geostore.com/environment-agency/survey.html#/survey?grid=TQ20

OS Terrain - 50m Grid or 10m Contours
https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html

USGS SRTM 30m
https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to the nice answer from [@Clubdebambos](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/56064/clubdebambos), assuming you are studying at a UK-based university, you may also have access to the [Edina Digimap](https://digimap.edina.ac.uk/) as this also contains OS Terrain data where you can select the tiles you're interested in:

- Contour lines and spot heights:

  [image: DEM]
- Merged digital terrain models:

  [image: Merged DTM]

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your help. However, we've downloaded data from both of these sites but when opening in ARC map the data doesn't have an attribute table. How do we access this?

Comment: @CharlieMason - Assuming you're talking about raster layers, QGIS at the moment does not support attribute table for rasters. Therefore, I can't test for Arc as I use QGIS. Apologies :)

Comment: @CharlieMason if you have downloaded the data as ascii just open it in Notepad, all the values are there. Some other raster formats will also open in Notepad. If you want to view in Arc convert the raster to points (Raster to Point tool) and view the attributes of the point which will have the X, Y and Z values.